# Paypal login session then saves it for faster checkout

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

Well, I was wondering if it is possible to automatically logins the user in paypal everytime they checks out?

Given the scenario a new user registers in my site.

```
New User->Logins to paypal->get permissions(etc..)->approve->gets back to my site
```

So, everytime the user checks-out it automatically logins in paypal.
I would like to link his paypal account to his profile in my site thus easier check out

I saw the documents but it is just too much for me to comprehend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are referring to reference transactions.  With PayPal you can create a billing agreement, and you would save the billing agreement ID to the local user record in your database.

In the future when they are logged in and checking out on your site you can pull the billing agreement ID and pass that into a reference transaction request to PayPal.  This will immediately process the new payment without any approval necessary, so you can simply display the order complete page to the user.

Their experience would be choosing their saved payment method, clicking to buy, and the complete page would show up immediately.  No checkout forms or login (other than logging in to your site) necessary.

Depending on whether you're working with the Classic API or REST the specific calls would be different, but "reference transactions" and "billing agreements" are the terms you're looking for.

Comment: I'll try this. Will come back for clarifications

Comment: hello, I have set another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42250216/where-to-find-billing-agreement-id-then-use-it-in-checkout