# Where to find Billing agreement ID then use it in checkout

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox

Hello everyone I am confused as to where to find the Billing agreement ID (BAID) after the user approves the billing plan.

*USING REST-API*

so far paypal returns this after I execute the agreement.

```
Agreement {#346 ▼
  -_propMap: array:9 [▼
    "id" => "I-N61SE6562BGN"
    "state" => "Active"
    "description" => "This is a subscription fee for using Talent Scout. It will be use to maintain the site and make users secure."
    "payer" => Payer {#349 ▶}
    "plan" => Plan {#350 ▶}
    "links" => array:5 [▶]
    "start_date" => "2019-06-17T07:00:00Z"
    "shipping_address" => Address {#364 ▶}
    "agreement_details" => AgreementDetails {#365 ▶}
  ]
}
```

I am confused if the ID in the above code is the BAID or not. If it is the BAID i'm looking for then I would like to insert it in the check-out so the user won't have to login again for future check-outs.

*Code when the user chooses and checks-out*

```
$payer = new Payer();
    $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');
    $total = 0;
    Session::set('duration', $request['duration']);
    if($request['duration'] == '1'){
        $item_1 = new Item();
        $item_1->setName('1 week duration') // item name
        ->setCurrency('PHP')
        ->setQuantity(1)
        ->setPrice($request['hiddenprice'][0]); // unit price
        $total = $request['hiddenprice'][0];
    }
    elseif($request['duration'] == '2'){
        $item_1 = new Item();
        $item_1->setName('2 weeks duration') // item name
        ->setCurrency('PHP')
        ->setQuantity(1)
        ->setPrice($request['hiddenprice'][1]); // unit price
        $total = $request['hiddenprice'][1];
    }
    elseif ($request['duration'] == '3') {
        $item_1 = new Item();
        $item_1->setName('3 weeks duration') // item name
        ->setCurrency('PHP')
        ->setQuantity(1)
        ->setPrice($request['hiddenprice'][2]); // unit price
        $total = $request['hiddenprice'][2];
    }

    // add item to list
    $item_list = new ItemList();
    $item_list->setItems(array($item_1));
    $amount = new Amount();
    $amount->setCurrency('PHP')
        ->setTotal($total);
    $transaction = new Transaction();
    $transaction->setAmount($amount)
        ->setItemList($item_list)
        ->setDescription('Your transaction description');
    $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
    $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(\URL::route('payment.status'))
        ->setCancelUrl(\URL::route('payment.status'));
    $payment = new Payment();
    $payment->setIntent('Sale')
        ->setPayer($payer)
        ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
        ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
    try {
        $payment->create($this->_api_context);
    } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PPConnectionException $ex) {
        if (\Config::get('app.debug')) {
            echo "Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
            $err_data = json_decode($ex->getData(), true);
            exit;
        } else {
            die('Some error occur, sorry for inconvenient');
        }
    }
    foreach($payment->getLinks() as $link) {
        if($link->getRel() == 'approval_url') {
            $redirect_url = $link->getHref();
            break;
        }
    }
    // add payment ID to session
    Session::put('paypal_payment_id', $payment->getId());
    if(isset($redirect_url)) {
        // redirect to paypal
        return Redirect::away($redirect_url);
    }
    Session::flash('failed', 'Something went wrong!');
    return Redirect::to('/home')
        ->with('error', 'Unknown error occurred');
    }
```

*Code when the payment is success*

```
// Get the payment ID before session clear
    $payment_id = Session::get('paypal_payment_id');
    // clear the session payment ID
    Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');
    if (empty(Input::get('PayerID')) || empty(Input::get('token'))) {
        Session::flash('failed', 'Something went wrong!');
        return Redirect::to('/paymentprocess')
            ->with('error', 'Payment failed');
    }
    $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $this->_api_context);
    // PaymentExecution object includes information necessary 
    // to execute a PayPal account payment. 
    // The payer_id is added to the request query parameters
    // when the user is redirected from paypal back to your site
    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayerId(Input::get('PayerID'));

    //Execute the payment
    $result = $payment->execute($execution, $this->_api_context);
    // echo '<pre>';print_r($result);echo '</pre>';exit; // DEBUG RESULT, remove it later
    // dd($result->id);
    if ($result->getState() == 'approved') { // payment made
        $data = new Paypalpayment;
        $user = User::find(Session::get('id'));
        $data->id = null;
        $data->payment_id = $result->id;
        $data->user_id = Session::get('id');
        $data->firstname = $user['firstname'];
        $data->lastname = $user['lastname'];
        $data->state = 'pending';
        $data->duration = Session::get('duration');
        $data->save();
        Session::forget('duration');
        Session::flash('success', 'Payment Successful!');
        return Redirect::to('/paymentprocess')
            ->with('success', 'Payment success');
    }
    Session::flash('failed', 'Payment failed!!');
    return Redirect::to('/paymentprocess')
        ->with('error', 'Payment failed');
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the ID in the return object after executing the agreement will be the billing agreement ID, which may be used to lookup information about the agreement at a later time.

Here's another example that may help: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/blob/master/sample/billing/ExecuteAgreement.php

Comment: I see. Does Paypal-REST API has reference transaction? I can't seem to find it. I intend to use this function https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoReferenceTransaction_API_Operation_NVP/

Comment: Yes, you'll want to take a look at billing plans (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/billing-plans/) and billing agreements (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/billing-agreements/). The billing plan sets up the architecture of the subscription, and the agreement binds a user, or users, to billing plan details

Comment: Yes, I did the two but I asked guys in https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK and they said it doesn't exists. I am forced to do alternate way to solve my problem. Thanks

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do in the subscription exactly. Reference transactions, chained payments, and parallel payments from Adaptive Payments and Express Checkout are not currently supported in the REST APIs, but are coming soon. So, what's the use case that you are trying to accomplish?